# Update table inner join

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join

I have two tables and i need to update one of them with respect to the id's of the second table

first table **successlog**;

```
Id     pid      shiftid
1       2          
2       2          
3       2          
4       5          
5       5
6       6
7       6
```

second table **employeelist**;

```
Id    pId      shiftid
1      2          1
2      5          1
3      6          2
```

I need to update the first table's `shiftid` with respect to the `pid` in the two tables.

I'm using the below query but its not working;

```
        $sql1="UPDATE successlog
                SET successlog.shiftid = employeelist.shiftid
                 FROM successlog
                 INNER JOIN employeelist
                 ON successlog.pid=employeelist.pId";
```

Answer (score 1):

You statement must look like this:

```
$sql1="UPDATE successlog INNER JOIN employeelist  ON successlog.pid=employeelist.pId
            SET successlog.shiftid = employeelist.shiftid";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE successlog 
INNER JOIN employeelist
ON successlog.pid=employeelist.pId 
SET successlog.shiftid = employeelist.shiftid
```